# jquery.autocomplete - Illegal characters in path

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

I am using the jquery.autocomplete plugin and when it makes the Ajax request it is giving me HTTP error code 500, and the body of the message says illegal character in path.

I am using MVC3 and I have moved the javascript code from the view to a seperate script file which is refereneced in my _layout.cshtml file. Before I moved my javascript it was working but now it doesn't and I don't understand why.

**Autocomplete.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("one");
    $("#group_name").autocomplete('@Url.Action("LookUpGroupName", "UserManager")', // Call LookUpGroupName ActionResult in UserManager Controller
        {
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        parse: function (data) {
            var rows = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                rows[i] = {
                    data: data[i],
                    value: data[i].group,
                    result: data[i].group
                }
            }
            return rows;
        },
        formatItem: function (row, i, max) {
            return row.group;
        },
        width: 300,
        highlight: false,
        multiple: false
    }); // End of autocomplete
    alert("two");
});
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Custom/autocomplete.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
           <div id="title" >
    <h1 style="color:Black">ALF and BRAD User Manager</h1>
</div>
<div id="logindisplay">
    <span style="color:Black; background-color:white; border-color:Black; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; text-align:right;">
        Logged in as:&nbsp<strong>@Context.User.Identity.Name</strong>
    </span> 
</div>

            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")&nbsp&nbsp
                    @Html.ActionLink("User Management", "Index", "UserManager")&nbsp&nbsp
                    @Html.ActionLink("User Status", "Index", "UserStatus")&nbsp&nbsp
                    @Html.ActionLink("Email Distibution List", "Index", "EmailDistributionList")&nbsp&nbsp
                    @Html.ActionLink("Email User Details", "Index", "EmailUserDetails")&nbsp&nbsp
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**View**

```
<!-- Declare model to be used for view -->
@model UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create New User";
}
<h2>
    CreateUser</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New User Details</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.salutation)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.salutation)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.salutation)
        </div>
       @{Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_AutocompleteGroupName.cshtml", this.ViewData);
}
```

[image: Ajax Response]

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET MVC jQuery autocomplete with url.action helper in a script included in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553377/asp-net-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-with-url-action-helper-in-a-script-included-in-a) I believe solves your problem - you are getting illegal characters because it is trying to go to: `http://localhost:51395/UserManager/@Url.action(%20 ... etc`

the @Url.action is not being parsed when the file has been moved to an external script because javascript is not run through that parsing engine what with it being server side.

Comment: That helped its making a request and the http response contains the json but the dropdown selection isn't rendering.

Comment: It was originally set to json before I started changing it to work from external js file. But changing it to json doesn't fix it.

Comment: Yes, in IE Developer tools I can see the data being returned in json format but I have a console error which says "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addClass' 
jquery.autocomplete.js, line 671 character 4
"

Comment: That is very odd, if it previously worked before moving. Is it working in any other browsers? sometimes IE can be finicky and the only issue I can see that might trip it up would be a closing ; on rows[i] = {
                    data: data[i],
                    value: data[i].group,
                    result: data[i].group
                }; any chance you can post a link to the page?

Comment: I have decided to write the javascript for my autocomplete on my _layout.cshtml page so I can use a partial view on any of my views and the autocomplete works. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = '<%=@Url.Action("GetValue","TaskNew") %>';
```